# Python Selenium - Webdriver interacts with data from previous page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to create a piece of code that takes an input from the user and searches for that input in his gmail account and then checks all the boxes from the sender which is the same as the input.
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Remote
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import urllib

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("http://www.gmail.com")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id('Email')
elem.send_keys("****************")
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_id('next')
elem2.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

elem3 = driver.find_element_by_name('Passwd')

elem3.send_keys("*************")

driver.find_element_by_id('signIn').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.implicitly_wait(20)

inp = 'randominput'

driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys(inp)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.gbqfb').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

x = driver.current_url

for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.zA.zE'):
print(i.find_element_by_class_name('zF').get_attribute('name'))
if(i.find_element_by_class_name('zF').get_attribute('name') == inp):
    i.find_element_by_css_selector('.oZ-jc.T-Jo.J-J5-Ji').click()
```

This main problem is that although the webdriver shows the new page where it has searched for the query but when the code interacts with the page it interacts with the previous one.

I have tried putting implicit wait. And when I check for the current url it shows the new url.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this is a single page app so selenium isn't going to wait for new data to load. You need to figure out a way to wait for the search results to come back. Whether it be based off of the 'Loading...' that appears at the top or even just waiting for the first result to change.

Answer (score 0):

Grab an element off of the first page and wait for it to go stale. That will tell you that the page is loading. Then wait for the element you want. This is about the only way to ensure that the page has reloaded and you aren't referencing the original page with a dynamic page.

To wait for stale, see `staleness_of` on http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html.